# control flow graph generator from C code

Tags: c++

can anyone give me the C++ source code to make a control flow graph generator for C language.
here i need to show any C program code as a control flow graph.
that's why i want to need the source code to make control flow graph generator.

Comment: Just browse github.

Comment: ohh..but i can not found any c++ source code to make control flow graph from c program....if you will find ,then pls give me the link....

Comment: Just a quick browse on the repositories and one can see repositories with C code (e.g. https://github.com/Kitware/CMake) and c++ code (e.g. https://github.com/gahansen/Albany).

Comment: sorry, i searched almost all the respositories but i can not find anything about control flow graph in those two links........

Comment: The question suggested to me that you want to create a program to create control flow graphs and for this you need example C / C++ code. But from the comment I understand you want to have a C++ program and revert this to a C program.

Comment: Are you ***sure*** that you need source code? Would you not accept a closed source program that does this?

Comment: yes. i want c++ source code to make this program(control flow graph generator). because i want to add some extra feathers  in this program......

Comment: See http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/FrontEnds/CppFrontEnd.html

Answer (score -1):

I suggest to take a look at [doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/index.html) and its possibility to generate flow graphs via [graphviz](https://www.graphviz.org) visualization software. You find the sources and documentation through the provided links.

I use both libraries for code documentation and flow graph generation extensively, but myself never made customization to the source.

Comment: doxygen does not output the control flow, but can output a list / graph of used functions and variable. Might be that Moritz (http://moritz.sourceforge.net/) might be something that can do something you want although its is more or less for Nassi-Schneiderman diagrams.